# Masking a UIView with another UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, mask

I've added a pan gesture to move `contentView` in my cell. I've also added a shadow to the `contentView` and resized the `contentView` as shown in the picture.

[image: cell]

Why I'm trying to do is, whenever I move the `contentView`, I'd like it be clipped. But because it's superview (`self.view`) has to remain it's original size I can't use: `self.clipsToBound = true`.

I've also tried adding a mask to the layer of `contentView` but since it's moving together it doesn't help much.

So I've added another view with the same original bounds as `contentView` acting as it's mask using: `contentView.mask = maskView`. But this still doesn't work as shown below.

I've added a border to show where it should be masked:
[image: moved]

**Question:**
Is there a way to mask the `contentView` with another view without adding it as subview?